# jquery hide not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this code to add row in a table mvc (jquery-1.7.1)

```
  <div id="model-form">    
    @Html.Partial("_FormXXX", Model)    
  </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button-aggiungi-riga").click(function () {
        $.post("mypage", $("form").serialize(), function (data) {
            $("#model-form").html(data);
        });

        ShowHideRows();
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".rimuovi-riga", function () {
        // set true in hidden field to set removed
        $(this).next().val("True");

        ShowHideRows();
        return false;
    });

    ShowHideRows();
});

function ShowHideRows() {
  $(".riga").each(function () { //loop over each row

    if ($(this).find("input[id$=__Removed]").val() == "True") {
      $(this).hide(); 
    }
    else {
      $(this).show();
    }

  });
}
```

In the asp.net mvc partial view, i have the following code

```
<tr class="riga">
   <td>
    ...
   </td>
   <td>
      <input class="rimuovi-riga" type="button" value="-" />
      @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Removed)
   </td>
</tr>
```

The function `ShowHideRows` is called from other functions (eg. `DeleteRow`) and i know it works. When i call it from `$("#button-aggiungi-riga").click`, it doesn't work.
I debugged it in firebug and the find and the `val()` value are correct.
It's showing all the rows. (I'm not getting `Style=display:hidden`).

Comment: Is it possible to see a jsFiddle?

Comment: It's asp.net, i can't reproduce row creation

Comment: can you just post a screenshot of your output? Is it showing? Or is it not showing correctly?

Comment: It's showing all the rows. Edited the post

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Did you try to put your `ShowHideRows()` inside `$(document).ready(function () {})` ? Since it looks @ `$(".riga")` it seems important.

Comment: How can i post screenshot? i tried to upload image but i need 10 reputation

Comment: "Nella partial ho" is more amusing than it should be.

Comment: There is ShowHideRows in document ready. I update the visible state of every row when the page load, when i delete a row and when i add a row.

Comment: Mmm if i move  ShowHideRows()  after $("#model-form").html(data);
it seems work

Comment: @Emanuele welcome to stackoverflow, please add proper tags to you questions.